# inline update in mysql using jquery/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm performing `CRUD` oprations using `JQuery/Ajax and php/MySQL`

i'm able to `insert/select` and `delete` data but i gotta stuck in edit/update. im pulling data into text box when i click on edit button but after editing when i click on save button unable to update in mysql db!!

Any help is Appreciated Thanks

**html code**

```
<span class="noedit name" idl='<?php echo $row->id;?>'>
    <?php echo $row->url;?>
</span>
<input id="url1" name="url1" class="form-control edit name url1" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>"/>

<a ide='<?php echo $row->id;?>' id="edit" class='editOrder' href="#" style="display:block-inline;">EDIT</a>
<a idu='<?php echo $row->id;?>' id="update" class='update saveEdit' href='#' style='display:none;'>SAVE</a>
<a idc='<?php echo $row->id;?>' id="cancel" class='cancelEdit edit' href='#' style='display:none;'>CANCEL</a>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$('body').delegate('.edit','click',function(){
    var IdEdit = $(this).attr('ide');
    alert(IdEdit);
    $.ajax({
        url:"pages/feeds.php",
        type:"post",
        data:{
            editvalue:1,
            id:IdEdit
        },
        success:function(show)
        {
            $('#id').val(show.id);
            $('#url1').val(show.url);
        }
    });
});

$('.update').click(function(){
var id = $('#id').val()-0;
var urls = $('#url1').val();
$.ajax({
    url:"pages/feeds.php",
    type:"post",
    async:false,
    data:{
        update:1,
        id:id,
        upurls:urls
    },
    success:function(up)
    {
        $('input[type=text]').val('');
        showdata();
    },
    error:function(){
        alert('error in updating');
    }

});
});
```

**PHP Code**

```
if(isset($_POST['editvalue']))
{
    $sql = "select * from test where id='{$_POST['id']}'";
    $row = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_object($row);

    header("Content-type:text/x-json");
    echo json_encode($rows);
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $sql = "
        update test
        set 
            url='{$_POST['upurls']}'
        where id='{$_POST['id']}'
    ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result)
    {
        //alert('success');
        echo 'updated successfully';
    }
    else
    {
        //alert('failed');
        echo 'failed to update';
    }
}
```

Comment: Deleted my comment because it was wrong. Instead, could you make sure you have the correct table name? The ones you have in your first and second queries differ, `test` and `deccan`.

Comment: @DarthGualin sorry its test on both ones forgot to mention it thanks!!

Comment: in your update button you mention class as class='update saveEdit' and on the click event you mention update , it should be replaced with saveEdit

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an #id input in your code. is it there?
 I think the problem is here.

If this input exists, use the following tips:
 
Check if all values (id, url) are sended to your PHP script.
 
You can use `console.log` in Javascript or `print_r`, `var_dump` functions in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
$('.update').click(function(){
```

to

```
$('.saveEdit').click(function(){
```

Comment: @Dan Lowe why -1, can you please check the code and my answer.